# MD5 Hashing function outputs garbage

Tags: c++, hex, md5, output

I'm working on a C++ class, and we're learning about the MD5 hashing function.  I'm running into this issue however, where I do something like:

```
string input = "testInput";
unsigned char *toHash = new unsigned char[input.size()+1];
strcpy( (char*)toHash, input.c_str() );

unsigned char output[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

MD5(toHash, input.size(), output);

cout << hex << output << endl;
```

But I always get some weird garbage characters instead of what I'm looking for, something like a long string of numbers / letters. What's going on?

~
Very confused by low level C++

Comment: The hash function generates a binary string containing the hash; you will need to convert that to hex or whatever other representation you want to use.

Comment: Ok but it's generating that binary string into the unsigned char array right? I don't understand why the bits don't get interpreted as unsigned char's when that happens, which would let you just output them via cout...

Comment: That "garbage" is also known as an md5 digest. :-)

Comment: So, some of the characters will be control characters (0x00..0x1F, 0x7F..0x9F); any null bytes will 'null terminate' your 'string'.  Some characters will be ASCII (assuming a normal code set, such as CP1252 or 8859-1), and the rest will be accented characters or other special punctuation, etc.  Either way, it will look like 'garbage'.  You need to print each byte separately, probably as 2 hex digits.

Comment: @user1288167, they *are* being interpreted as unsigned chars. That fact that you consider some of the characters to be "garbage" is beside the point. What do you actually want the output to be? A sequence of hex digits?

Comment: @user1288167 an MD5-hash is a binary digest of the source data. If you want it in hex-string form, then translate every byte into a pair of alpha-chars ('0'..9,'A'..'F') and store them in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get fooled by the "unsigned char" type of the array, all that means here is that each value in the array is going to be an 8-bit unsigned integer.  In particular it *doesn't* imply that the data written to the array will be human-readable ASCII characters.

If you wanted to see the contents of the array in human-readable hex form, you could do this (instead of the cout command):

```
for (int i=0; i< MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) printf("%02x ", output[i]);
printf("\n");
```